# Usage of "all but"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct usage if "all" is dropped as well? For instance, if I say "The box contains but a small number of books," instead of "The box contains all but a small number books," is it still grammatically correct?

Comment: It's not a complete sentence, so hard to tell. Do you know what "all but" means?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here I meant to use it as "all except a few." I've completed the sentences in my original post.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical, well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, both sentences may be grammatically correct, but they have different meanings.

As you know, "all but" means 'all except' whereas "but" as used here would suggest the meaning 'only'.

> "The box contains all but a small number (of the) books" means
>
> the box contains all the books **except** a small number.

This sentence is constructed right if you mean that the box contains all except a few (of the) books, those few books being elsewhere (not in the box.) On the other hand,

> "The box contains but a few books" means
>
> the box contains **only a few** books.

Is that what you wanted to say?

In short, dropping the 'all' from 'all but' will **change the meaning** of your sentence from "all except a few" to "only a few." You can choose which to use depending on what you meant to say.